# how to detect if a graph is hamiltonian

Tags: data-structures, recursion, graph-algorithm

I have an assignment question that ask to implement the interface method `isHamiltonian`, I tried to solve the problem by using recursion.

The idea is simply try all paths from a node, if there is a path that satisfy the conditions

- travel all the nodes only once
- the last node is directly connected to the first node

I will say it is Hamiltonian.

I have tried these code, but it does not work

```
public static boolean isHamiltonian(Graph g) throws InvalidGraphException {
    if (g == null || !(g instanceof GraphI) || ((GraphI) g).getDirected()) {
        throw new InvalidGraphException();
    }

    NodeI[] nodes = (NodeI[]) g.nodes();
    if (nodes.length < 3)
        return false;

    return isHamiltonian(nodes[0], nodes[0], new HashSet<NodeI>());
}

private static boolean isHamiltonian(NodeI start, NodeI n, HashSet<NodeI> hs) {
    hs.add(n);
    NodeI[] nodes = n.getReachableNeighbours();
    boolean connectedWithStart = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
        if (nodes[i].compareTo(start) == 0) {
            connectedWithStart = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (hs.size() == n.getGraph().nodes().length && connectedWithStart) {
        return true;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
        if (!hs.contains(nodes[i]))
            isHamiltonian(start, nodes[i], hs);
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: `does not work` is a very general thing to say. What is not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me that your backtracking is the problem. You greedily add nodes to your `hs` to build your path but you don't remove them when you fail to make a cycle/don't have any way to go.

The first thing I would do is put `hs.remove(n)` before the final `return false`.Then I would also save the result of `isHamiltonian(start,nodes[i],hs)` and exit when it's true. Something like this

```
boolean result = isHamiltonian(start,nodes[i],hs);
if(result)return true;`
```

That should fix up a lot. I do think that this exhaustive search will be quite slow.

**EDIT**: the whole thing should look like this:

```
private static boolean isHamiltonian(NodeI start, NodeI n, HashSet<NodeI> hs) {
    hs.add(n);
    NodeI[] nodes = n.getReachableNeighbours();
    boolean connectedWithStart = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
        if (nodes[i].compareTo(start) == 0) {
            connectedWithStart = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (hs.size() == n.getGraph().nodes().length && connectedWithStart) {
        return true;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
        if (!hs.contains(nodes[i])){
            boolean result=isHamiltonian(start, nodes[i], hs);
            if(result)return true;
        }
    }
    hs.remove(n);
    return false;
}
```

The problem itself is NP-hard so don't expect fast solutions for general graphs. Read up on [some basic algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path_problem#Algorithms) and decide if it's worth the time to implement for your application.